# $().find in Query

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is my code, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 it works but when i get into ajax success 9,10 can not work (it cannot detect my #pcs_tdh_tsp in current row of the table

```
function giasalessanpham_nhap()
{
     $('#customers2').find('tr').click( function(){
        var masp = $(this).find('#pcs_tdh_masp').val(); //1
        var slsp = $(this).find('#pcs_tdh_slsp').val(); //2
        var gnsp = $(this).find('#pcs_tdh_gnsp').val(); //3
        var gssp = $(this).find('#pcs_tdh_gssp').val(); //4
        var lnsp = numberWithCommas(gssp - gnsp); 
        var tttt = numberWithCommas(gssp * slsp); 
        $(this).find("#pcs_tdh_lnsp").css("color", "red"); //5
        $(this).find("#pcs_tdh_tttt").css("color", "red"); //6
        $(this).find('#pcs_tdh_lnsp').val(lnsp); //7
        $(this).find('#pcs_tdh_tttt').val(tttt); //8
        $.ajax({
            url:baseurl+"/laythongtinsanphamtheomaajax/", 
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {masp : masp},
            success:function(data) {
                thue = data['pcs_cl_pd_thue'];
                $(this).find('#pcs_tdh_tsp').css("color", "red"); //9
                $(this).find('#pcs_tdh_tsp').val(thue); //10
            }
        });//ajax
    });     
}
```

Comment: Because `this` is no more related to `click` event but ajax itself.

Comment: You could just use `context: this` as ajax option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should save your `this` value into local variable before get it in `success` ajax callback like this:

```
function giasalessanpham_nhap()
{
     $('#customers2').find('tr').click( function(){
        //1,2 ... 8
        var selector = $(this); //save
        $.ajax({
            url:baseurl+"/laythongtinsanphamtheomaajax/", 
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {masp : masp},
            success:function(data) {
                thue = data['pcs_cl_pd_thue'];
                //here you work with your selector
                selector.find('#pcs_tdh_tsp').css("color", "red"); //9
                selector.find('#pcs_tdh_tsp').val(thue); //10
            }
        });//ajax
    });     
}
```

What's really happened is that inside `success` ajax callback you have different context so `this` is different than inside your `click` handler.

Answer (score 0):

that's because this doesn't refer to the same object anymore, you should save the value of $('#customers2')
try this:

```
function giasalessanpham_nhap()
{
     $('#customers2').find('tr').click( function(){
        var masp = $(this).find('#pcs_tdh_masp').val(); //1
        var slsp = $(this).find('#pcs_tdh_slsp').val(); //2
        var gnsp = $(this).find('#pcs_tdh_gnsp').val(); //3
        var gssp = $(this).find('#pcs_tdh_gssp').val(); //4
        var lnsp = numberWithCommas(gssp - gnsp); 
        var tttt = numberWithCommas(gssp * slsp); 
        $(this).find("#pcs_tdh_lnsp").css("color", "red"); //5
        $(this).find("#pcs_tdh_tttt").css("color", "red"); //6
        $(this).find('#pcs_tdh_lnsp').val(lnsp); //7
        $(this).find('#pcs_tdh_tttt').val(tttt); //8
        var that = $('#customers2');
        $.ajax({
            url:baseurl+"/laythongtinsanphamtheomaajax/", 
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {masp : masp},
            success:function(data) {
                thue = data['pcs_cl_pd_thue'];
                that.find('#pcs_tdh_tsp').css("color", "red"); //9
                that.find('#pcs_tdh_tsp').val(thue); //10
            }
        });//ajax
    });     
}
```